# Deadlock in mpich-3.3 but not in other versions

Tags: c++, mpi

I have the following program which compiles and run with openmpi and mpich-3.2.1, but a deadlock appears at the `MPI_Waitany` call with mpich-3.3.
The program must be run with an even number of ranks, half of which are sending data to the second half through an intercommunicator.
This is a much smaller version than a larger custom simulation program, I tried to make a minimal example.

One weird part is that increasing the `nwork` variable to 2 makes the deadlock disappear.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <vector>

const int endMsg = -1;
const int endTag = 424242;

class Work
{
public:
    Work(const MPI_Comm& comm, const MPI_Comm& interComm, int tag) :
        comm(comm), interComm(interComm), tag(tag)
    {
        MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);
    }

    void waitPrevSend()
    {
        printf("[work %d] waiting for previous message\n", tag);
        MPI_Wait(&sizeReq, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        MPI_Wait(&dataReq, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        sizeReq = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;
        dataReq = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;
    }

    void workAndSend()
    {
        waitPrevSend();
        printf("[work %d] creating data\n", tag);
        data.resize(tag + 42, tag);
        sizeInBytes = data.size();
        MPI_Issend(&sizeInBytes, 1, MPI_INT, rank, 2*tag+0, interComm, &sizeReq);
        MPI_Issend(data.data(), data.size(), MPI_BYTE, rank, 2*tag+1, interComm, &dataReq);
        printf("[work %d] has sent %d bytes of data\n", tag, sizeInBytes);
    }


    MPI_Request wait()
    {
        MPI_Request req;
        printf("[work %d] posted recv of size\n", tag);
        MPI_Irecv(&sizeInBytes, 1, MPI_INT, rank, 2*tag+0, interComm, &req);
        return req;
    }

    void recv()
    {
        data.resize(sizeInBytes);
        MPI_Recv(data.data(), data.size(), MPI_BYTE, rank, 2*tag+1, interComm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printf("[work %d] has recved %d bytes of data\n", tag, sizeInBytes);
    }


    MPI_Comm comm, interComm;
    int rank;
    int tag;


    MPI_Request sizeReq {MPI_REQUEST_NULL}, dataReq {MPI_REQUEST_NULL};
    std::vector<char> data;
    int sizeInBytes;
};

class Master
{
public:
    Master(const MPI_Comm& comm, const MPI_Comm& interComm) :
        comm(comm), interComm(interComm)
    {
        MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);
    }

    void run(std::vector<Work>& work, int niter)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < niter; ++i)
            for (auto& w : work)
                w.workAndSend();
        sendEndMsg();
    }

    void sendEndMsg()
    {
        MPI_Ssend(&endMsg, 1, MPI_INT, rank, endTag, interComm);
    }

    MPI_Comm comm, interComm;
    int rank;
};

class Slave
{
public:
    Slave(const MPI_Comm& comm, const MPI_Comm& interComm) :
        comm(comm), interComm(interComm)
    {
        MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);
    }

    void run(std::vector<Work>& work)
    {
        std::vector<MPI_Request> reqs;
        for (auto& w : work)
            reqs.push_back(w.wait());
        reqs.push_back(recvEndMsg());

        while (true)
        {
            int id;
            MPI_Status status;
            printf("waiting for one of %d requests to complete\n", (int) reqs.size());
            MPI_Waitany(reqs.size(), reqs.data(), &id, &status);

            if (id == (int) reqs.size() - 1)
            {
                for (auto& req : reqs)
                {
                    if (req != MPI_REQUEST_NULL)
                    {
                        MPI_Cancel(&req);
                        MPI_Request_free(&req);
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                work[id].recv();
                reqs[id] = work[id].wait();
            }
        }
    }

    MPI_Request recvEndMsg()
    {
        MPI_Request req;
        int msg;
        MPI_Irecv(&msg, 1, MPI_INT, rank, endTag, interComm, &req);
        return req;
    }

    MPI_Comm comm, interComm;
    int rank;
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int rank;
    int size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if ((size%2) != 0)
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);

    MPI_Comm teamComm, interComm;
    int team = rank % 2;

    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, team, rank, &teamComm);

    const int localLeader  = 0;
    const int remoteLeader = team ? 0 : 1;
    const int tag = 42;
    const int nwork = 1;

    MPI_Intercomm_create(teamComm, localLeader, MPI_COMM_WORLD, remoteLeader, tag, &interComm);

    std::vector<Work> work;
    for (int i = 0; i < nwork; ++i)
        work.emplace_back(Work(teamComm, interComm, i));

    if (team == 0)
    {
        Master master(teamComm, interComm);
        master.run(work, 10);
    }
    else
    {
        Slave slave(teamComm, interComm);
        slave.run(work);
    }

    MPI_Comm_free(&interComm);
    MPI_Comm_free(&teamComm);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Running

```sh
mpirun -n 2 -l ./test_intercomm
```

results in a deadlock only in mpich-3.3. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I also tried to reduce the stopping tag to something smaller as suggested, same behavior.
The output of the above command is:

```
[0] [work 0] waiting for previous message
[0] [work 0] creating data
[0] [work 0] has sent 42 bytes of data
[1] [work 0] posted recv of size
[1] waiting for one of 2 requests to complete
[0] [work 0] waiting for previous message
```

So the rank 1 deadlocks at the waitany and the rank 0 deadlocks while waiting for the send request to complete (second one, actual data, whose recv is only posted by rank 1 once it has passed the waitany).
To me it seems that the `MPI_Waitany` blocks everything.

Comment: At what point does it deadlock? How far does it get? If the deadlock appears when the end message should be sent, try making `endTag` smaller (tag values are only guaranteed to be valid up to 32767, after that it is defined by the MPI library).

Comment: Just found this maybe related bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mpich/+bug/1802372

Comment: @rtoijala thanks for the suggestion, `endTag=42` gives the same result (see edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in MPICH v3.3. It is fixed in the commit [0f7be7196cc05bf0c908761e148628e88d635190](https://github.com/pmodels/mpich/commit/0f7be7196cc05bf0c908761e148628e88d635190). Applying the fix to v3.3 resolves the deadlock.

The fix is included in version 3.3.1, so you should upgrade to that.

To give more context, the commit message says:

> Both testany and waitany functions skip over inactive or NULL requests
>   before handing down to the device layer. However, the method for
>   discovering the first non-NULL request could erroneously skip the
>   first request in the array. To fix, we initialize the first non-NULL
>   request to an invalid index in the array (count) and set to valid
>   index later if one is found.

Comment: Great that sounds exactly like the cause of my bug. Will upgrade and try again, thank you very much!